# Hosting Docusaurus v2 using Nginx

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, docusaurus

I'm attempting to use nginx as the reverse proxy to host Docusaurus v2 on Google AppEngine.
GooglAppEngine has HTTPS turned on. And Nginx listens on port 8080. Hence by default all requests are over HTTPS and the connections managed by Google AppEngine.

However, I'm having an issue when users perform the following actions :

- Reach the landing page
- Go to documentations (any page).
- Refresh the page.

The user is getting directed to port 8080 and not the https site of docusaurus.

Without refreshing the page, the user is able to successfully navigate the site. It's when the user hits a refresh button that they get the redirect. Looking at the header information, I see the response pointing them to port 8080 but I'm not sure why that is happening.

Wondering if anyone has successfully been able to set up Docusaurus v2 with nginx ?

My config for nginx is as follow :

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console when logged to this
    # directory.
    access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
    error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        # Google App Engine expects the runtime to serve HTTP traffic from
        # port 8080.
        listen 8080;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }
        }
        


    }
```

Comment: Where are you hosting the reverse proxy, is it a GCE instance or do you have it somewhere else?

Comment: It's a Google AppEngine flex environment with nginx as a reverse proxy on the AppEngine serving up Docusaurusv2.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to the docusaurus website linking to directories without trailing slash `/`, causing a redirect which is setup to include the port by default.

Looking into the docusaurus build directory you will see that your pages are defined as folders containing index.html files. Without the `/` the server needs to redirect you to `{page}/index.html`.

Try to call the URL with `/` and no port, which should be successful:

```
https://{host}/docs/{page}/
```

Therefore fixing the problem, you could try to change the redirect rules to not include the port with the `port_in_redirect` parameter:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    port_in_redirect off;
    
    # More configuration
    ...
}
```

See the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect) for more details.

Comment: for me ngnix redirect changed port, server_name and schema... `absolute_redirect   off;` works for me

Answer (score 0):

To solve "go to documentations (any page)" and "refresh the page" problems you can use:

```
location / {
    ...
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    ...
}
```